# CloudKit + CoreData on iOS and watchOS sync not working

Tags: ios, core-data, apple-watch, cloudkit

I have a iOS + watchOS app that I want to use the same data model. So I created a CoreData stack and I set up everything for `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`.

My iOS app can access the CloudKit container as I can read from the logs in the console, however when my watchOS app wants to connect to the CloudKit container (same `iCloud.foo.myID` as the iOS app) I get an error saying `Invalid bundle ID for container`.

I tried several new containers. I also retried to check all checkboxes on the capabilities pane again and again.

Am I missing something?

(I also read [Core data + CloudKit - sharing between iOS and watchOS companion app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58905655/core-data-cloudkit-sharing-between-ios-and-watchos-companion-app) which did not help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem. Solution for me was make xcdatamodel shared for both app (in my case it's not standalone app for watch, but extension).
So just check the box for share this model for both app:
[image]

Also set class generation to Cathegory/Extension or Manual, because you need a little bit different implementation of entity class for iOS and WatchOS. If someone know how to use one class and checking which OS call the instance it will be perfect.

[image]

Comment: I chose writing my own classes over code generation and now it works. Who could have know that the default option is not working. Thanks Apple. Thanks Ku6ep